# Extensible provisioning protocol tools in php

Tags: php

I am looking for EPP(Extensible provisioning protocol) tools which are written in php.

I found "https://www.centralnic.com/registry/labs/preppi" which is in perl for linux and unix systems.

I have found "https://epptool-ctld.verisign-grs.com/epptool/" But it is supported for limited tlds.

I want this tool so that from my side no coding is required. If I give input suppose for domain registration. the epp request should be created and sent to the particular epp server.

Any suggestion on php based EPP tools are appreciated. 
Or PHP based API's.

Answer (score 3):

> I found "https://www.centralnic.com/registry/labs/preppi" which is in perl for linux and unix systems.

That's not true [CentralNic](https://www.centralnic.com) has both [PERL](http://code.google.com/p/perl-net-epp/) and [PHP](https://github.com/centralnic/php-epp) Versions and its very easy to use if you have [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) installed on both windows or unix

Example

```
require ('Net/EPP/Client.php');
$client = new Net_EPP_Client();
$host = 'epp.nominet.org.uk';
$port = 700;
$timeout = 10;
$ssl = true;
$greeting = $client->connect($host, $port, $timeout, $ssl);
echo $greeting;
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nominet.org.uk/epp/xml/epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
  <greeting>
    <svID>Nominet EPP server epp.nominet.org.uk</svID>
    <svDate>2008-08-23T16:24:51Z</svDate>
    <svcMenu>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <lang>en</lang>
      <objURI>http://www.nominet.org.uk/epp/xml/nom-account-1.0</objURI>
      <objURI>http://www.nominet.org.uk/epp/xml/nom-domain-1.0</objURI>
      <objURI>http://www.nominet.org.uk/epp/xml/nom-contact-1.0</objURI>
      <objURI>http://www.nominet.org.uk/epp/xml/nom-ns-1.0</objURI>
    </svcMenu>
    <dcp>
      <access><all/></access>
      <statement>
        <purpose><admin/><prov/></purpose>
        <recipient><ours/></recipient>
        <retention><indefinite/></retention>
      </statement>
    </dcp>
  </greeting>
</epp>
```